# How can I prevent grid-auto-flow from creating new columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a ul of unknown length.

I want to arrange this ul into a grid. The grid must have 4 columns and be column-based, like follows:

```
1  6  11 16 
2  7  12 17 
3  8  13 18 
4  9  14 
5  10 15
```

This can be achieved with:

```
ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-rows: 10px;
}
```

However, if I then add more li's into the ul, it overflows and begins creating new columns:

```
1  6  11 16 21 
2  7  12 17 22 
3  8  13 18 23 
4  9  14 19 
5  10 15 20
```

when what I want is for it to create new rows, because I can only have 4 columns:

```
1  7  13 19 
2  8  14 20 
3  9  15 21 
4  10 16 22 
5  11 17 23
6  12 18
```

How can I block the creation of new columns and force only new rows to be created?

I don't believe I can use a flexbox with `flex-direction:column` and `flex-wrap:wrap`, as I don't have a defined height of the final ul.

I've even tried to create a grid using `grid-auto-flow:row` and then transpose it using transforms, but I think that will only work for square grids.

Question has been marked as duplicate, but the other question only wants to know know to make the grid flow in columns.

Comment: Why are you not using CSS columns instead of CSS grid?

Comment: Not possible, to the best of my knowledge, with the [current iteration of CSS Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/).

Comment: @connexo please make an answer and I'll mark it as accepted